# Regex to get everything starting with @ and removing everything after any non-included characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following:

```
        Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]");
        foreach (var item in source.Split(' ').Where(s => s.StartsWith("@")))
        {
            var mention = item.Replace("@", "");
            mention = RgxUrl.Replace(mention, "");
            usernames.Add(mention);
        }
```

**CURRENT INPUT > OUTPUT**

- `@fish and fries are @good` > `fish`, `good`
- `@fish and fries and @Mary's beer are @good` > `fish`, `good`, `marys`

**DESIRED INPUT > OUTPUT**

- `@fish and fries are @good` > `fish`, `good`
- `@fish and fries and @Mary's beer are @good` > `fish`, `good`, **`Mary`**

The key here is to remove anything that's after an offending character.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your current code outputs `fish`, `Marys` and `good`. Perhaps, all you need is `Regex.Matches(source, @"(?<!\S)@([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value)`.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(theInput, @"(?<=@)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToList()`

Comment: I do not see where in your code you change the case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Typo - case doesn't matter.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You split a string with a space, check if a chunk starts with `@`, then if yes, remove all the `@` symbols in the string, then use a regex to remove all non-alphanumeric, `-` and `_` chars in the string and then add it to the list.

You can do that with a single regex:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(source, @"(?<!\S)@([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", res)); // demo
usernames.AddRange(res); // in your code
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/huCV6S)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - there must not be a non-whitespace symbol immediately to the left of the current location (i.e. there must be a whitespace or start of string) (this lookbehind is here because the original code split the string with whitespace)
- `@` - a `@` symbol (it is not part of the subsequent group because this symbol was removed in the original code)
- `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` - Capturing Group 1 (accessed with `m.Groups[1].Value`) matching one or more ASCII letters, digits, `-` and `_` symbols.

Comment: If you need to turn the case to lower, just use `.Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value.ToLower())`